# AngularJS submenu in directive with ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-show

I have made a directive for my sidenav. In my sidenav I have some elements that have submenu items under them. At the moment I can toggle only one element in the sidenav, but I need atleast 2-3 more. How should I implement it ?

My directive code:

```
menuItem.directive("menuItem", function() {
 return {
     restrict: "E",
     template: "<div ng-click='toggle($event)' ng-transclude></div>",
     transclude: true,
     scope: {
         hash: "@",
         show: '=',
     },
     link: function($scope) {
         $scope.toggle = function(e) {
            $scope.show = !$scope.show;
         }

     }
 }
 });
```

My html code:

```
<menu visible="leftVisible" alignment="left">
<menu-item hash="first" show="someVar">

    Side Menu item
    <ul ng-show="someVar">
        <li>
            <a>First submenu item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>First submenu item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="second" show="someVar">

    Side Menu item
    <ul ng-show="someVar">
        <li>
            <a >Second submenu item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a >Second submenu item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</menu-item>
<menu-item hash="third">Side Menu item</menu-item>
</menu>
```

My goal is that I can open submenus individually with ng-show in the sidenav, any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed list of menu items, you can use separate variables for each menu item, like this

```
<menu visible="leftVisible" alignment="left">
    <menu-item hash="first" show="menu1">

        Side Menu item
        <ul ng-show="menu1">
            <li>
                <a>First submenu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>First submenu item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </menu-item>
    <menu-item hash="second" show="menu2">

        Side Menu item
        <ul ng-show="menu2">
            <li>
                <a >Second submenu item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a >Second submenu item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </menu-item>
    <menu-item hash="third">Side Menu item</menu-item>
</menu>
```

In this case variable `menu1` is responsible for visibility of the first item, `menu2` - visibility of the second one, etc.

But if you are iterating over some array, you can use a specific field for each menu item.

```
<menu visible="leftVisible" alignment="left">
    <menu-item ng-repeat="item in items" hash="{{item.hash}}" show="item.show">
        {{item.title}}
        <ul ng-show="item.show">
            <li ng-repeat="subItem in item.items">
                <a>{{subItem.title}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </menu-item>
</menu>
```

In this case you use `show` field for each array item.

Comment: At the moment when I click 2 menu links it opens both submenus, who should one implement that only one submenu is open at the time thus when you click on another menu item it closes all the other submenus?

Comment: Are you sure you've changed `show` value for the second item? The first one uses `menu1`, the second one - `menu2`. Take a look at the first code example

Comment: Sorry I phrased my question a little bit wrong, this solution works very well. What I meant was that how to implement case where lets  say I press menu1 and it shows it then I press menu2 and it shows it but I want that the menu1 closes when menu2 is pressed and etc.